# Find out workflow action id/code/name

Tags: jenkins, jira, jenkins-plugins

I have installed [JIRA Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JIRA+Plugin) for Jenkins and set up a post-build step to make a comment in Jira:

[image]]

Where to find the correct name/id for the workflow action? Because I am getting this error:

> [JIRA] Unable to update issue ******-**: invalid workflow action "In
>   Testing". Perhaps the Jenkins user does not have permission to perform
>   the action on the JIRA issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you look at your JIRA project issue next to the Status: field you should be able to (View Workflow) which will show you the ticket creation workflow and options you can choose from.  The jenkins JIRA user will only be able to move along those steps of the workflow in order.  It would be my guess that In Testing is not a valid Workflow Action for your JIRA project.  Also check that your jenkins user has the ability to create and modify tickets on the project you are trying to open tickets against.

Comment: "In Testing" as a valid workflow state. I tried also "Done" -- din't work.